# How to create a rule to assign roles to users based on some checkbox items in their profile?

Tags: 7, rules, users

I am pretty new to Drupal. I am using [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) so that the user can select there own user role. So say I have a profile page with some checkbox items like

- Automotive
- Computer
- Garden
- etc

How would I add a condition or data comparison in Rules to say, If Automotive is selected/checked, set user role to that role? I also need to be able to select multiple checkboxes to get multiple roles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 1 - Make it work for a single selection and related role

Create a rule which looks like so:

1. **Rules Event**: After saving user profile.
2. **Rules Conditions** (both conditions must be satisfied):

   - entity has field (with the field corresponding to (eg) "Automotive".
   - data comparison to check if "Automotive is selected/checked".
3. **Rules Action**: : Assign role to user (for the role related to "Automotive").

You could create a similar rule for each possible combination of checkboxes and roles to be assigned. Or continue as detailed in Part 2 to further enhance your rule from Part 1 so that you end up with a single rule for all possible combinations.

## Part 2 - Make it work for other possible combinations

To also make it work for other possible combinations, and because of the fact that a Rules action cannot contain "conditions", you basically have 2 possible approaches:

- Create a similar rule (as in Part 1) for each possible combination.
- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to enhance the *Rules Action* in the above rule to alter the flow, using either ***Conditional*** (if/else) of ***Switch*** logic. Be aware: this module only has a beta release for D7, though it's used in over 8K sites (which makes it seem like a pretty robust module though).

Comment: Wow, thank-you so much. This information is very helpful!